# Proving the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

I am looking to prove the Pigeonhole Principle by proving the following claim:

Let $A$ be a set with $m$ elements, and let $B$ be a set with $n$ elements, where $m,n\in \omega$ and $m > n$. Suppose $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$. Then $f$ is not injective.

I am looking to eventually show that $f$ is not a bijection from $A$ to $B$ by proving that $\require{cancel}A \cancel{\sim} B$ (in case that symbol is tough to read: $A$ is not equinumerous to $B$).

I am having trouble getting started though. I have that $\{1,...n\}\subset \{1,...,m\}$, but I am unsure where to go from here to get my desired result.

Any direction is appreciated!

Comment: The Pigeon hole principle is roughly "Given n holes and m pigeons with m>n, at least one hole has more than one pigeon". I wouldn't be looking to see whether or not something has an injection or a bijection. Rather, I would say given a set $\{1..n\}$ and $\{1..m\}$ with $n<m$, show there is NO injection from $\{1..m\}\hookrightarrow \{1..n\}$. I.e for any map, there is some $x\neq y$ (two distinct pigeons) in $\{1..m\}$ such that $f(x) =f(y)$ (the same hole).

Comment: There is a more detailed version, with $m$ pigeons and $n$ holes, there must be some hole with at least $\lceil \frac{m}{n}\rceil$ pigeons.  E.g. $10$ pigeons and $3$ holes, there must be a hole with at least $4$ pigeons.

Comment: Yes, I thought thats what I was doing. By showing that an arbitrary function, $f:A\to B$ is not bijective (and thus not injective), aren't we showing that there is NO function that is injective from $\{1,...,m\}$ to $\{1,...,n\}$?

Comment: @JMoravitz is suggesting a relatively beautiful property combinatorically that works for finite sets. You may want to try proving it if you can get a bearing on the general proof. Moreover, the general proof works for TRANSFINITE sets as well which leads to the uncountable pigeon hole principle in which things get a little more interesting. For the basis of your proof, I suggest a proof by induction and try to incorporate enumerations but that's simply because that's the only way I have seen it done. I'm sure there are others that are probably better.

Comment: Bijective is a little much though. Assuming surjectivity does not help your case what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

An example would be:

A={1,2,3,4,5};
 B={1,2,3,4}

If we say that $\forall a\in A,  !\exists b\in B:b=a$, we have a=b=1;a=b=2;a=b=3;a=b=4 but we can't assign a new value that equals 5. so 5 is not able to be paired up. In essence, this is all the pigeonhole principle is saying. It can be restated as, if you have two sets, such that one set has a higher cardinality than the other, you can't pair the elements of these sets in a way that avoids pairing up the same value in the smaller set twice ( or n times for the general case). We call this smaller set the pigeonholes, and the larger one the pigeons.